# How to execute a function in my view model when page loads

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I want to run an "init" function that is in my view model. I am having a hard time figuring out how to reference it.

**home-page.xml**

```
<Page
    navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

    <ActionBar>

        <NavigationButton ios:visibility="collapsed" icon="res://menu" tap="onDrawerButtonTap"></NavigationButton>

        <ActionItem icon="res://menu" 
            android:visibility="collapsed" 
            tap="onDrawerButtonTap"
            ios.position="left">
        </ActionItem>
        <Label text="Use Tickets"></Label>
    </ActionBar>

    <GridLayout rows="60, *, 60" width="100%" height="100%"
        backgroundColor="lightgray">
        <Label text="Label 1" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="red" />

        <StackLayout height="100%" row="1">
            <Label height="50%" text="{{ LabelTop }}" tap="{{topTap}}"></Label>
            <Label height="50%" text="{{ LabelBottom }}" tap="{{bottomTap}}"></Label>

        </StackLayout>
        <Label text="{{ expDate }}" row="2" col="0"
            backgroundColor="blue" />

    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

**home-page.js**

```
const app = require("tns-core-modules/application");

const HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");

function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
    HomeViewModel.init();
}

function onDrawerButtonTap(args) {
    const sideDrawer = app.getRootView();
    sideDrawer.showDrawer();
}

exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
exports.onDrawerButtonTap = onDrawerButtonTap;
```

and lastly, here is my view model. As you see, I have an init function that I want to run when the user first gets to this page:

**home-view-model.js**

```
// Required Includes
const observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
const httpModule = require("tns-core-modules/http");
const appSettings = require("tns-core-modules/application-settings");
const navigation = require("../shared/navigation.js");
const security = require("../shared/security");


function HomeViewModel() {
  var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({

    // Observables
    pageTitle: "Use Tickets",
    expDate: calcFutureDate(),
    LabelTop: "1 Monthly",
    LabelBottom: "Unlimited",
    expText: "Expiration Date and Time",
    username: null,
    appValid: false,


    // Methods
    topTap: function (args) {
        alert("Here!");
      const tLabel = args.object; // handle to top label area
      elStack = tLabel.parent;

    },

    bottomTap: function (args) {
      const bLabel = args.object; // handle to bottom label area
      console.log(bLabel.id);
    },

    // Init Function
    // !!!  THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO RUN !!!
    init: function(args){
        if(security.isFirstRun()){
            alert("First run");
        } else {
            alert("not first run");
        }
    }



  });

  return viewModel;

}

function calcFutureDate() {
  let numWeeks = 1;
  let now = new Date();
  now.setDate(now.getDate() + numWeeks * 7);

  var curr_date = now.getDate();
  var curr_month = now.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  var curr_year = now.getFullYear();

  return curr_month + "-" + curr_date + "-" + curr_year;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```

I have tried all sorts of things to get this function to fire:

HomeViewModel.init()

viewModel.init()

init()

and so on, and so on.

Thanks for looking. Any help would be appreciated.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `home-page.js` can you create an instance of `HomeViewModel`, do `init` and then bind context? Reading through the docs here https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding under sections "Binding to a plain object" and "Binding to a parent binding context" in the javascript example? Or is that what you meant when you said you tried "`viewModel.init()`" ?

Something like this

```
function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    const page = args.object;
    const viewModel = new HomeViewModel();
    viewModel.init();
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;
}
```